# How to store a span value that doesn't have id or name into database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this calorie calculator page, and everything is on a single page(PHP, HTML, Javasript). I am trying to store all the form values into the database with the code below,and it works fine except the values of the spans in the div with results class, I have no idea how to store them. These are the results I am trying to store :

```
<div class="results">
        <div id="calc-target-gain">
            To Gain Weight:<br>
            <span>2700 calories</span>
        </div>
        <div id="calc-target-maintain">
            To Maintain:<br>
            <span>2400 calories</span>
        </div>
        <div id="calc-target-lose">
            To Lose Weight:<br>
            <span>1900 calories</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the full code:

```
<?php
    if( isset(
        $_POST['submit'],
        $_POST["gender"],
        $_POST["age"],
        $_POST["height"],
        $_POST["weight"],
        $_POST["calc-target-gain"],
        $_POST["calc-target-maintain"],
        $_POST["calc-target-lose"],
        $_POST["type"]
    )) {
        
        require 'connect.php'; 
        
        # prepare data for insert - in same order as columns in sql below.
        $args=array(
            $_POST["type"],
            $_POST["gender"],
            $_POST["weight"],
            $_POST["height"],
            $_POST["age"],
            $_POST["calc-target-gain"],
            $_POST["calc-target-maintain"],
            $_POST["calc-target-lose"]
            
        );
        # create a string of variable type identifiers for the prepared statement.
        $types=str_repeat( 's', count( $args ) );
        
        # prepare the sql command with placeholders
        $sql='INSERT INTO calculators 
        ( cType, gender, weight, height, age, cResult, toGainResult, toMaintainResult, toLoseResult, bmiCategory)
        VALUES
        ( ?,?,?,?,?,"0",?,?,?,"null")';
            
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$args );
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('calorie_calculator.php'); </script>";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Simple Calorie Calculator using JavaScript - @code.scientist x @codingtorque</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Further Code Herre -->   
    <div id="bmr-calculator" class="wrapper">
    
    <form id="CalForm" method="POST" style="margin: 5vh 20vw;" onreset="formReset" >
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="choose-gender">
            <div class="segmented-control"><input id="calc-gender-male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"
                    checked=""><label for="calc-gender-male">Male</label></div>
            <div class="segmented-control">
                <input id="calc-gender-female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><label
                    for="calc-gender-female">Female</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label for="calc-age" id="calc-age_value">Age: 25</label>
        <input id="calc-age" type="range" name="age"value="25" min="13" max="100">
        <label for="calc-height" id="calc-height_value">Height: 180cm</label>
        <input id="calc-height" type="range" name="height" value="180" min="80" max="250">
        <label for="calc-weight" id="calc-weight_value">Weight: 80kg</label>
        <input id="calc-weight" type="range" name="weight" value="80" min="40" max="200">
        <label for="calc-walking" id="calc-walking_value">Walking: 2 hours per week</label>
        <input id="calc-walking" type="range" name="activity"value="2" min="0" max="50">
        <label for="calc-cardio" id="calc-cardio_value">Cardio: 1 hour per week</label>
        <input id="calc-cardio" type="range" name="exercise" value="1" min="0" max="50">
        <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type"value="Cal" >
    </div>
    <div class="results">
        <div id="calc-target-gain" name="calc-target-gain">
            To Gain Weight:<br>
            <span>2700 calories</span>
        </div>
        <div id="calc-target-maintain">
            To Maintain:<br>
            <span>2400 calories</span>
        </div>
        <div id="calc-target-lose">
            To Lose Weight:<br>
            <span>1900 calories</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"class="btn btn-skin btn-sm">
    </form>
</div> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"
        integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <script>
        $(".calculator input").on("input change", function (event) {
    var parameterName = $(this).attr("id").split("calc-")[1];
    var centimeters = $(this).val()

    switch (parameterName) {
        case "height":
            $("#calc-height_value").html("Height: " + centimeters + " cm");
            break;
        case "weight":
            var kg = $(this).val();
            $("#calc-weight_value").html("Weight: " + kg + " kg");
            break;
        case "age":
            $("#calc-age_value").html("Age: " + $(this).val());
            break;
        case "cardio":
            $("#calc-cardio_value").html("Cardio: " + $(this).val() + " hours per week");
            break;
        case "walking":
            $("#calc-walking_value").html("Walking: " + $(this).val() + " hours per week");
            break;
    }

    var height = parseInt($("#calc-height").val(), 10);
    var age = parseInt($("#calc-age").val(), 10);
    var weight = parseInt($("#calc-weight").val(), 10);
    var walking = parseInt($("#calc-walking").val(), 10);
    var cardio = parseInt($("#calc-cardio").val(), 10);
    var gender = $(".calculator input[name='gender']:checked").val();

    // The Harris–Benedict equations revised by Mifflin and St Jeor in 1990: 'A new predictive equation for resting energy expenditure in healthy individuals'
    var bmr = parseInt(10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age, 10) + (gender === "male" ? 5 : -161);
    bmr = bmr * 1.2;
    bmr += walking * 60 * (.03 * weight * 1 / 0.45) / 7;
    bmr += cardio * 60 * (.07 * weight * 1 / 0.45) / 7;
    bmr = Math.floor(bmr);

    var targetGainWeight = Math.round((bmr + 300) / 100) * 100;
    var targetMaintain = Math.round((bmr) / 100) * 100;
    var targetLoseWeight = Math.round((bmr - 500) / 100) * 100;

    $("#calc-target-gain span").html(targetGainWeight );
    $("#calc-target-maintain span").html(targetMaintain + " calories");
    $("#calc-target-lose span").html(targetLoseWeight + " calories");
});
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried to put a name on divs before the span like this:
name="calc-target-gain", i tried the same on the span itself, but it didnt work also.

please advise if you require further clarification

Comment: divs/spans etc aren't form elements and will there for not be submitted with the form. If you want the content to be part of the form, then you can create hidden inputs for those values. When you set the values in those divs/spans in your JS, you can then also set the value of the corresponding hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the goal would be. I couldn't find the URL in your code where you want to send the data. (Maybe `calorie_calculator.php`?)

If you send data using a "form" and not with the help of JavaScript, you can only use input fields. However, **you can use a "hidden" field** to transmit things like CSRF tokens or other IDs.

More information: [<input type="hidden">](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp)

I prefer using sending processes declared in JavaScript.

If you want to pass a larger dataset beyond the input fields in the request, it needs to be associated with the request.

**You can also send a request using native JavaScript with the `fetch` method.**

More information: [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

For example:

```js
function sendFormByFetch() {
  // YOUR CALCULATIONS
  // ... [HERE] ...

  // USING FETCH API, and can use your calculated variables

  // 1.) declare what we want to send
  let data = {
    targetGainWeight: targetGainWeight,
    targetMaintain: targetMaintain,
    targetLoseWeight: targetLoseWeight,
  };

  // 2.) send "data" to url (can set method and headers)
  fetch("/calorie_calculator.php", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, 
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  // 3.) interpret the received response
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
  });
}
```

In this case, the button needs to be told to execute this function instead of performing the form event.

```html
<button id="myButton" onclick="sendFormByFetch()">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input element, combined with JavaScript to pass the data to the form.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("test-input")
const div = document.getElementById("span-container")
const span = div.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]

input.value = span.innerText
console.log(input.value)
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="test-input" name="test-input">
<div id="span-container">
  <span>Hello, World!</span>
</div>
```